# Change color of the Switch Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change the color of a Mui Switch https://material-ui.com/api/switch/.

I am able to change the color of the "ball" by doing:

**styles.ts**

```
switchStyle: {
  '& span.MuiSwitch-switchBase': {
    color: 'red'
  }
}
```

**HOWEVER** I would like to change the remaining part of the Switch, the grey part.
See image:
[image]

Comment: You can use custom CSS: `.MuiSwitch-track { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was not able to find the Mui class. Now I tried `'& span.MuiSwitch-track': {backgroundColor: "red" }` at it works